# What goes in the Exception field of a Throw Activity

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

Can anyone tell me how to use the Exception field of the Throw Activity?

I need specific examples.  I'm throwing an exception as I need to capture it in the calling code and then run some clean up code.

Thanks for any help

Richard

In reply to Chuck

I tried the following and the workflow cancels but the execution doesn't enter the catches.
Any idea why?

```
public class AbortException : System.Exception
{
}

class manager
{
    ...

    try
    {
        workflowApp.Run();
    }
    catch (AbortException ea)
    {

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    ...
}
```

with an Exception Property of: New AbortException

Comment: What are you talking about? The [`ThrowActivity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.componentmodel.throwactivity.aspx) doesn't have an `Exception` field - or property.

Comment: In wf4 there is an activity called Throw which has an Exception Field. I have seen mention of a ThrowActivity but I have not seen one in the toolbox.

Comment: Oops, that should have been: The ThrowActivity is WF3 not WF4

Comment: Show us the code that throws the AbortException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is to create a class that extends exception and pass any values you want, like:

```
public class MyError : Exception
{
   public MyError() : base(string.Empty) {}
   public MyError(Exception e) : base(e.Message) {}
   public int MyCustomValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then using it like, (passing the value of 5 to the catch handler)

```
throw new MyError(){ MyCustomValue = 5 };
```

Then in your catch

```
try{}
catch(MyError ex)
{
    Console.Write(ex.MyCustomValue.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is most useful.  I've done as you suggested and I can see the workflow stopping but I my catch does not fire.

Comment: Does your `workflowApp.Run();` do a `throw new AbortException();` within it?  If it doesn't, then it won't catch it.

Answer (score 3):

You are still using a WorkflowApplication here right?

Is so it executes on a different thread so a C# try/catch around the Run() won't help. You need to add a handler to the OnUnhandledException event as I pointed out in you other question.

```
WorkflowApplication wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(new YourWorkflow());
wfApp.OnUnhandledException = e => UnhandledExceptionAction.Abort;
wfApp.Run();
```